# Task.Start, Task.RunSynchronously and synchronization context

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task, synchronizationcontext

I construct a task manually:

```
var task = new Task(() => 
    Debug.WriteLine("Task"));
```

Then start it manually:

```
task.Start(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

I expect it to be be scheduled via `SynchronizationContext.Post`.

But if start it this way:

```
task.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Will it be executed via `SynchronizationContext.Send`, or directly by calling the task's lambda?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Will it be executed via SynchronizationContext.Send, or directly by
>   calling the task's lambda?

Here's what's going on. First, `Task.RunSynchronously` tries to execute the task by calling `scheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline`. In case with `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler`, it's this:

```
protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
{
    return ((SynchronizationContext.Current == this.m_synchronizationContext) && base.TryExecuteTask(task));
}
```

So, if on the same synchronization context, the task lambda will be executed directly inside `base.TryExecuteTask`.

Otherwise, `Task.RunSynchronously` queues the task with the task scheduler, and blocks on the task's `WaitHandle` with the blocking wait.

`SynchronizationContext.Send` does **not** get involved in any case.

What's interesting about this. AFAIK, in WPF there may be several `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` contexts on the main UI thread, one per top-level window. Thus, in theory, `RunSynchronously` may result in a deadlock. I'm going to verify this.

**Updated**, the deadlock in WPF is **real**. Here is how to repro:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sMainWindow, RoutedEventArgs eMainWindow)
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
            Debug.WriteLine("Task"));

        var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        var window1 = new Window();
        window1.Loaded += (sWindow1, eWindow1) =>
        {
            // Deadlock in WPF
            task.RunSynchronously(scheduler);
            Debug.WriteLine("Done!");
        };
        window1.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having a hard time envisioning the deadlock, here. Do you mind describing how this results in a deadlock? i.e. who is competing for what held resource?

Comment: @Thomas, there is no racing, but the task completion callback is posted via SynchrnizationContext.Post, and then the thread blocks on the same task's handle inside task.RunSynchronously, resulting in a deadlock. I'm going this from the phone, do can't go into more details, but you could search for Stephen Clearly's "don't block on asynchronous code".